# Downvotes in chat

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, chat, down-votes

There should be an option to downvote in chat.

Chat is very tied to SO, and almost all rooms have well defined basic rules.

I believe strongly that being able to downvote off-topic or run-by questions in chat would very much discourage such irritating behavior. It is also much more humane than letting room regulars either completely ignore or pound the new person in to the ground.

*(edit)* The current system is lacking in user-self-regulation like on all the other SE sites. Room owners aren't always as present and vigilant as downvote-capable users (that are active and present at the time of the incident) could be.

I speak out of my personal experience (it's not me being ignored or drive-by-question dropping, it's others) in the Lounge, which is a great room if you understand the relaxed mentality governing the regulars' chatting behavior.

**EDIT** To respond to the comment of "the downvoting system is not described here". This is a discussion post, meant to discuss the option. The implementation depends on the outcome of this discussion, obviously. I was thinking `-5` rep on the "mother site" to which the user's profile is linked. This is just an example!

Comment: What effect would these downvotes have - how would they discourage the activity you're seeing in chat? Would they affect the poster's reputation on SE? Which site? Or would chat now have its own reputation system? What would downvotes cost the caster? What about upvotes? You've proposed one small piece of what could be a very complex system.

Comment: As I think about it, most of the behavior that I'd want to down-vote is from ignorance, which is treated by pointing them at the FAQ.  It's pretty rare for me to want to downvote someone who has such been informed.  Which means downvotes don't accomplish anything except make me feel better.

Comment: You're really missing important details as to why this would be good and why the current system does not work

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Chats are linked to a specific SE site, so logically, it'd affect that linked site's rep.

Comment: I'd imagine the existing flagging system could be more reasonably extended to handle whatever issues you're seeing in chat. Any by the by - examples? What behavior, exactly, are you seeing that you'd rather not?

Comment: @rubenvb Not necessarily - chat users have a "parent site" for historical reasons, but it can be almost anything. I can be participating in chat on Math.SE and have my parent account be set to Stack Overflow, for example.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: I don't know what you think happens, but flagging is an utterly broken and horrific system that we never, ever use.

Comment: Care to explain that, @DeadMG? That's not a helpful comment otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta The flagging system needs moderators to respond, which is just as slow as a inactive or not caring room owner.

Comment: There suddenly seems to be a lot of feature requests just to keep questions out of a single SO room...

Comment: @BenBrocka: They're extremely irritating and disruptive, and the other rooms have the same problems as us. We just tend to come here and complain about it more.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Flagging for a moderator requires a moderator, and flagging for other users disrupts the chat for *everybody* by making them respond to a single message completely out of context.

Comment: As far as I understand, there are automated systems that listen to flags - one triggers a short ban from the room. Otherwise, I'm suggesting *extending* the flagging system, not *replacing* it with a new, complex one.

Comment: @BenBrocka: Since that room has the highest population, everyone with a question to post goes to that room so that everyone is forced to see their advertisement.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Yes- *after* it's already pissed off every 10k user in every room. We already tried to get it fixed.

Comment: @DeadMG, how exactly would a downvoting system, still not described here, make the situation any better?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: If a message is downvoted, it's easier for us to know which messages to bin, for example, and which users are problematic. Rep in the chat would serve the exact same purpose as rep on the main sites.

Comment: Ok, that's a start, @DeadMG. This proposal is getting a poor reception here in part because it lacks detail, as I allude to in my first comment. I think you'll have better luck once this proposal is fleshed out.

Comment: @BenBrocka: We're the bestest room and we care deeply about chat experience, and not just for us (also why we dislike the current flagging system).

Comment: rubenvb, I get where you're coming from, but even with a `discussion` tag here, MSO isn't chat. It's best if you come here with a reasonably fleshed-out proposal. *Then* we can discuss it.

Comment: +1.  Not nearly enough drama in chat.

Comment: @ruvenb Needing a mod to act isn't ineffective. IIRC, chat flags are first shown to all who can act on them present in theroom. If no action is taken (five minutes, I think), they are escalated to all chat.SE pages. There are enough mods online to deal with it (I've seen the flag notification quite a few times, but another mod usually gets there first, its handled nearly instantaneously)

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles you clearly haven't been to Lounge<C++> in the last few weeks. And I'll say it again: often flagged messages are dismissed out of context, resulting in *ineffective* flagging.

Comment: @rubenvb: Oh right, chat.SO--chat.SE mods can't touch it. Hmm, then a better fix (IMO) would be to (a) Implement [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86597/) and (b) allow chat.SE mods to moderate chat.SO.

Comment: @Manish `allow chat.SE mods to moderate chat.SO` **NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO**...

Comment: @YannisRizos: Hmm? What, scared of the millions of flag notifications you'll get?

Comment: @Manish It's not the volume of the flags that scares me, it's their content. Chat.SO is a weird & scary place.

Comment: @yannis hmm, but if the sites are kept separate, then you won't be bothered by the flags unless on chat.SO. That way, the chat.SE flags stay separate. Also, it's probably a scary place due to the lack of moderation (by moderation I don't mean handling flags. I mean handling flags and letting the user know what s/he did wrong). With the current number of mods, this is impossible.

Answer (score 15):

Linking chat activity to reputation on the main site is a **very, very bad idea**. Your activity in chat - positive or negative - contributes *nothing* directly to the main site, where folks are asking questions and getting answers. If you're annoying people in chat, they should be able to take action directly *in chat*.

> I believe strongly that being able to downvote off-topic or run-by questions in chat would very much discourage such irritating behavior.

A tool for this already exists: flag the post. If enough people do this, it gets deleted, and the author gets (a *very* short) suspension *from chat*. If that seems too severe to you, then you aren't *really* interested in discouraging anything.

Comment: As has been <strike>ignored</strike>stated repeatedly, the existing flagging system leaves a *lot* to be desired.

Comment: @DeadMG so suggest something that fixes that problem instead of creating a second awkward chat moderation tool

Comment: @BenBrocka: Pretty sure we already tried that.

Comment: @DeadMG: So suggest improvements to it, or refine existing suggestions for improvement (amusingly, the folks I see complaining about flagging tend to fall into two separate groups: the "we want flags to be more powerful" and "we hate censorship and want to stop flags from being effective" parties - if you can come up with something that resolves this tension better than the current system *without* also creating dictatorial walled gardens, I'd love to hear it). Start with examples of real problem - always a great way to get stuff done.

Comment: +1 -- Linking chat activity to the site in general is an awful idea IMHO (though that could be because I hang out in the sewer known as The Comms Room).  Chat is chat - it's a bunch of people gathered in a virtual bar to BS. The sites are "the office" where we "work" helping people get answers to their questions.  You might talk about the office at the bar, but if you spill your drink on someone your pay shouldn't be docked for the dry cleaning.

Answer (score 7):

So what you want is to tell the user "don't do that". Downvotes don't actually do that, they indicate quality. Indicating quality of isolated chat messages is problematic at best.

If someone is doing something they shouldn't, *tell them*. You'll still have to do that anyway, because when users get downvotes they're just going to ask why they got downvotes; they do the same thing on the main site. Then instead of saying "Hey, don't ask questions here" you're saying that, and explaining your downvote. So now you've got two problems, and drama on top of that.

It seems like what you *really* want is some sort of way to punish these users for being annoying. That's sort of understandable, but this would be a huge (and unusual) feature change that barely addresses the problem in any useful way.

If you want better community/room owner/ect tools for chat, request that with a specific suggestion. Downvotes just aren't the way to do that (and just imagine the hellish drama they would incite).

Comment: Chat messages are not isolated. If they are, the completely disconnected context is a good reason for a downvote. I also don't see what kind of hellish drama you see coming from this.

Comment: The problem is that if user X ignores it, and then simply comes back later to a different group in the chat, you have no way of knowing that. There's no history. It can take days for a user to get thoroughly ignored and flagged out of the room.

Comment: @DeadMG: how much of a problem is it that a single user does that?  Virtually never that I've been aware of.

Comment: @dead No history? Oh yes there is. Mods can see a list of flags on a user. Isn't that enough?

Answer (score 1):

`The current system is lacking in user-self-regulation like on all the other SE sites. Room owners aren't always as present and vigilant as downvote-capable users (that are active and present at the time of the incident) could be.`

Sounds like you need to add more room owners, not start re-architecting chat.  Just my humble opinion...

Comment: Room owners can't banish in public chat rooms. Flags are needed, which can be dismissed by random other chatters that fail to check the message's context.

Comment: @rubenvb I fail to see the *need* for flags to deal with this, though I could get behind giving room owners "kick" ability if you want a technical solution to "people are being chatty in chat"

Comment: It's not "chatty" I'm wanting to punish. It's all out disrupting. Like barfight disrupting.

Comment: @rubenvb And I can see the merit of giving room owners a way to deal with that (let them kick people).  Downvotes don't seem to be the right answer to me, for all the reasons Shog9 mentioned

Answer (score -1):

I agree. Wherever it is possible for bad behaviour to disrupt other users and the site in general, downvoting should be an option. And we already have a form of upvoting in starring things.

Comment: Stars aren't up-votes, and they *definitely* don't contribute to your reputation on the main site (or anywhere else).

Comment: @Shog9: The original proposal did not imply that down-votes would be tied to the rep on the main site, until his sample.  I rather like the idea of chat-specific rep. "Plays nice with others"

Comment: @Mooing: sounds like more of a distraction than anything else, IMHO. But that'd be a separate proposal at this point. Definitely against a system that allows punishing folks who are doing fine on the main site if they venture into chat - that's just a recipe for discouraging anyone who isn't part of the right clique from ever using it.

Answer (score -8):

I totally agree that many chats are off topic and adding downvote will regulate behavior for some people. 
There is concern though that this can have negative side as well. It can discourage some people to chat freely.

Comment: One of SE's most popular chat rooms, [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), rarely has any on-topic chat at all.

Comment: It's not about sticking to some preestablished topic, that's just silly.