# "Gallery" chat rooms should be reversed in functionality

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make it possible to revoke write access to public chat rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135734/make-it-possible-to-revoke-write-access-to-public-chat-rooms)

In light of the discussion sparked (mainly in `Lounge<C++>`) by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137300/148545), I would refresh the punishment proposal in there to be a much more simple "reversed Gallery chat".

Gallery rooms scare away new users with the manual entry. Just let new people chat, but if there's a problem, let them be kicked out pronto.

In my eyes there is no use in keeping users in an unchattable view of the room (why would they be kept at bay? To educate them by example?). Just let them in, but be denied service when they are obnoxious. This is much closer to real life (think bars, not private clubs) than how it is now.

Comment: I think the reason why banning was left out was because of the potential for abuse. But something definitely needs to be done about the the current situation in the C++ room. Perhaps allow owners with thousands of posts (maybe not a threshold, but some formula) to allow banning.

Comment: There's no difference between the "reversed Gallery" and the current Gallery: Room owners kick out people at their leisure. It's the entry that scares off new and occasional chatters which IMHO needs to disappear.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "reverse Gallery"? Do you mean allowing room owners (or whoever) to blacklist users and ban them from a specific room?

Comment: @AnnaLear Yes. Exactly: a Gallery without the manual entry admission is what I'm proposing.

Comment: That's the same as manual banning.

Comment: @rubenvb So... basically a normal chat room but some users can be banned? That sort of exists right now - users can be suspended from chat (although it's network-wide, not per room).

Comment: @Mysticial which is enabled for Gallery rooms. I don't get why you think excessiva abuse will come of this.

Comment: @AnnaLear I believe most Lounge<C++> regulars agree it is not enough and broken. Suspension needs either moderator intervention (slow) or verified flags (which are very hard to get on out-of-context `invalid` votes by totally unrelated chatters in some other room). No need for this ban to be network wide anyways: for the same reason that a rep link isn't wanted for chat.

Comment: Techincally, flagging can be used as a sort of vote-based banning. However, I reserve flags only for the most serious offenses - not the simple case of an annoying help-vampire.