# Let's do regular Meta SE Town Hall Chats (on hiatus)

Tags: discussion, chat, town-hall-chat

[Back in 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280309/join-us-for-the-second-mse-town-hall-on-wednesday-june-22nd), Ana conducted a couple of experimental "town-hall" chat sessions. They worked pretty well, so we all agreed to keep doing them...

...And then, uh, didn't.

That's a real shame. So, we revived the idea, [starting on the 12th of July](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/town-hall-3-12-july-2017). And we're gonna continue to do a half-hour session every two weeks-ish, varying the time a bit as we go, for total of 6 sessions. The last event of those six was held from 18:30 UTC to 19:00 UTC on September 27<sup>th</sup> 2017.

#### What's the topic?

Whatever happens to be going on that week! Current meta discussions, new features, that wretched chat rate-limiter... We'll pick a topic and introduce it, give folks a chance to discuss, and then move on, following [the format we used during the last test](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/mse-town-hall-2-chat-moderation-part-1).

#### Sounds dreadful. Where do I sign up?

No events are currently scheduled; future series will be announced here and listed in the bulletin.

#### I have thoughts that are at best tangentially relevant to any of this; where can I post them?

Hey, there's a comment box below; knock yourself out!

Comment: What is the purpose/necessity of registration? I'd like to at least lurk, but I can't guarantee that something else doesn't take priority at that time of day.

Comment: Registering gives you a mildly obnoxious alert if you're in chat and the event is about to start, @Josh. Also, I guess, lets me know that someone is interested enough to click a button. If you don't need or want that, you don't need to register.

Comment: Will the topic be announced in advance?

Comment: Probably not, @Monica. Aiming for a bit more informal, with the idea that if we do these often enough it won't be so high-pressure (for everyone).

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I hope the time does move around to give more people a chance to participate.

Comment: Why not feature this, so those not often in MSE will also notice?

Comment: I didn't realize chat didn't create an event for me, @Shadow. It *told me* it did. Lesson here is: **chat *lies*!** (I went and created the event manually)

Comment: @Shog9 Damn chat! How am I supposed to trust that?!

Comment: Will this include another google hangout with view of your as always spotlessly cleaned apartment, @Shog9 ?

Comment: Could the Town Hall last longer than 30 minutes so more people can join and more topics can be discussed (i.e longer time, multiple consecutive sessions with breaks in between)

Comment: After a few sessions we'll probably just start picking different times, @Anthony.

Comment: I'm registered, but may be one of those people who doesn't turn up - it's at 2.30am my time. But I'm sometimes awake at that time and did stay up for a 4.30am cogsci chat that was important for a total revaluation of the site. I don't put the Town Halls in that category.

Comment: Can we whine about moderators or is there another chat for that?

Answer (score 15):

Epilogue: September 27, 2017

Final episode in the initial 6-session series. Topic was voting fraud, past and future plans to more effectively control it. Also a wee bit of retrospective on this series.

Transcript can be found here: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/town-hall-chat-8-27-september-2017

---

Epilogue: September 13, 2017

Topic was "let's just talk about what we've been doing" - Jon shared some notes from the Documentation sunsetting and DAG liaisoning, bluefeet talked about the work she put in to create an epic answer to a hard question here on meta and also some of the SQL work she's been doing.

Open discussion involved how hard it can be to catch a CM.

Transcript can be found here: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/town-hall-chat-7-13-september-2017

---

Epilogue: August 23, 2017

Topic was [Reopen queue success rate by input source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355341/reopen-votes-queue-overrun-due-to-poor-approved-edits-rep-farming/355396#355396). A pretty obscure issue, but at least there were tables of numbers.

Also discussed: people who don't upvote the things one might wish they would, and do upvote the things one might wish they wouldn't. Anonymous feedback.

Transcript can be found here: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/town-hall-chat-6-23-august-2017

---

Epilogue: August 9, 2017

Topic was [The Sunsetting of Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation); much retrospective.

Transcript can be found here: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/town-hall-5-9-august-2017

---

Epilogue: July 26, 2017

The second event involved two topics, which was probably a mistake; we somehow didn't expect folks to be as interested in mentoring as they were, so crammed in a second topic which mostly just derailed a thriving discussion. Probably won't do that again!

Transcript can be found here: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/town-hall-4-26-july-2017

---

Epilogue: July 12, 2017

The first event went well - transcript can be found here: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/town-hall-3-12-july-2017

Topics included Channels, DAG, review, and feature-work.