# What happened to meta Town Hall chats?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, town-hall-chat

As the title of [the announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298165/lets-do-regular-meta-se-town-hall-chats-on-hiatus) suggests, Town Hall chats are currently on hiatus.

Why were they discontinued after six sessions? Weren't there plans to run them every two weeks? If I remember correctly, they brought in quite a few people from different branches about SE and allowed them to discuss things that weren't really being discussed by regulars.

So what happened that resulted in it not working out? Was it because it required too much work from too many employees to run?

I would really like to see it again. If we ever do decide to reinstate them, it would be very nice to have it in a dedicated chat room, rather than in Tavern on the Meta, the main chat room.

Comment: there is not a single featured tag on any of the edits to the announcement for the "Town Hall Chats". Were these ever featured or otherwise advertised in any way?

Comment: @JGreenwell I think they were primarily intended for active Meta.SE users.

Comment: To me that feels like either SE was trying to avoid SO users or just really didn't think about that fact that active Meta.SO users (and active participants in Documentation) [might not be active on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367493/was-there-a-documentation-post-mortem) - and might forget about there being a chat coming due to the month gap between announcement and event. I admit the former is more likely caused by recent perspective into SE's interactions to its users than was probable a year ago.

Comment: @JGreenwell That may be why it failed, but we can ask for it in this request.