# What are the benefits of chatrooms for asking questions?

Tags: discussion, chat, asking-questions

What are the benefits of using a chatroom instead of asking a question directly on a Stack Exchange site?

Answer (score 8):

- Sometimes, a question can be too broad or too opinion-based for the Stack Exchange Q&A sites. A simple example would be "I'm a Java developer, how do I get started with Python?" I'm not familiar with the culture of the Python chatroom on Stack Overflow, but they might be willing to help.
- If you have trouble phrasing your question correctly, or generating a <s>MCVE</s> [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), users in a chatroom might be able to help you interactively, in a better way than comments and/or downvotes on a poor question do.

  - Please don't forget to actually ask the question on the site if you think it has value for future visitors, even if you got the answer in chat already. The Q&A site is way more accessible and searchable than chat.
- You can ping certain knowledgeable people in chat, if you're specifically interested in what they think about your question. I would only do this if I knew that person well and that they're open to be invited like this. It's not something you should do as a new user, and it's something I'd do *in addition* to posting the question. In general, you want as much visibility to your question as you can get, and Q&A is much more visible than chat.

But chat is mostly used for other things than Q&A, e.g. [coordinated moderation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), (as a [side channel](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/38/2019/6/3)) for [live events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318428/295232), or just to chill.

Answer (score 4):

Chat's primarily a social space. You get the most out of it simply by hanging out, observing, and getting to know people.

It's not always the best place for asking questions. Rooms have very varying amounts of patience for such things.

In a chat room where people are familiar with me, and vice versa, I know some folks are subject matter experts. More importantly, I sometimes use the room to rubber duck problems that I know will be well-received, and workshop things that could be questions.

In the *right* chat room, and the *right crowd*, you often end up being able to work through issues. ([This specific one](https://superuser.com/questions/1194886/unable-to-do-release-update-on-ubuntu-14-04) was spectacular, and started with me complaining on chat that updating was borked, and it so happened someone on chat went "OOOH, can I take a look?") Knowing I'd post a question helped too ;).

In the right room, you can troubleshoot, step through problems, and so on.

What doesn't really work is the old IRC pattern of asking, waiting, asking again....

What works is knowing the room and knowing when and how to ask.

So... it's terrible, until you work out how to.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words and from a pragmatic and selfish point of view, asking a question in a chatroom saves the asker from getting a ban for asking bad questions. A question asked in a chatroom will never get closed. There are no ads in chatrooms.

The following might fall in the category that might or might not be a benefit based on the circumstances of the specific question and the asker's mindset.

In a chatroom, the participation rules are different than in the sites and per-child-metas. I.E. some sites don't allow emojis in questions, in a chatroom emojis might be allowed.

A question asked in a chatroom will never get up, and downvotes will never be converted in a *community wiki*, and will never be protected or locked. It will never get suggested edits. It will never appear in the Hot Network Questions. A meta-question asked in a chatroom will never be featured or appear as a *Hot Meta Question* in the *Community Bulletin*. A question asked in the chatroom will never appear in the *Community Digest*, and will never appear in the Global Search results. A question asked in a chatroom will never be included in the email notifications and the questions and tags in RSS feeds.

I think that Google doesn't index questions asked in a chatroom. I have never gotten a result pointing to any Stack Exchange chatroom platform instances (SO, SE, Meta SE).

The following adds a factor: chat with someone.

When the asker has someone to chat with, an interlocutor, there are chances to have a dialogue about the question. The question might get an answer in a chat message but might get other kinds of replies. Sometimes, the replies might lead to something equivalent to a site's high-quality answer, and sometimes not.

I believe that a chatroom could be used to help askers having problems writing a question according to the site rules to write the question.

I have seen people posting things on sites and per-child-metas stuff that are not "questions", according to the site and per-child-rules, like broad help requests. I also believe that a chatroom could help people looking for help with issues related to the site and per-child-meta topics that can't be handled as a question according to the site rules or due to the Q&A platform limitations. On sites about using software applications, a chatroom might be helpful to guide a user looking for help with an issue requiring combining heuristic and trial-and-error approaches, implying the possibility of having a lot of back and forth, sometimes referred to as *troubleshooting*.

## Related

## Featured

- [Where to ask for general advice for young programmers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216589/289691)

## Other

- [Web-based IRC for the Trilogy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48249/289691)
- [How to ask a good question if you don't know the subject very well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341731/289691)
- [Where can I ask questions that I don't know how to frame well enough for Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366769/289691)
- [General programming language questions in chat.stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376707/289691)

## Resources

- [Do Trilogy Sites Need a "Third Place"?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/29/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/)
- [Third Place Chat Beta Preview](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/14/third-place-chat-beta-preview/)