# What do I do if I have a technology-related question that doesn't quite fit anywhere?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a general question regarding why graphing calculators essentially stopped developing (or getting cheaper!) about 20 years ago, but none of the various "Exchanges" seem suited to that. Is there a "technology general" area I can post it to? Or like a history of technology forum or something similar?

I've love to hear from someone with some degree of knowledge regarding the field--which leaves much of reddit out.

Comment: I wonder - and you should doublecheck on *their* meta, if those count as retrocomputing.

Comment: I don't get the downvotes: this user is in the right place to ask for site-recommendation, explains their question, and tells us what they have tried so far.

Comment: Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. (Especially on main sites.) (See my edits on your now-posted question post & this post when/if approved. Please ask 1 specific researched question. (Asking a bunch of questions is a very poor substitute for 1 clearly scoped question.)

Comment: @philipxy All true, but suggesting an edit is the more constructive way to deal with those things, especially when it comes to new users.

Comment: @Joachim My 2 comments are unrelated.

Comment: @Joachim also, net "income" of 38 rep is pretty decent, rep-wise the OP is fine. In site-rec questions, I observed that people also tend to vote based on how on topic the question can be in SE in general. i.e. if there's indeed some site for it. When there is, we see more upvotes, when there isn't, well, usually more downvotes are coming. Fair or not is something that can be discussed on its own, but we can't change it, I'm afraid.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry Thank you. I wasn't really so much concerned about the reputation—at least, not the user's :) 'Fairness' would be especially ironic, since that would mean users would vote based on *their* understanding of the entire network, and questions that would actually be constructive (pointing to sites they're likely not aware of) would be disregarded. "*Ignorance is bliss*"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Programmable calculators are on-topic at Retrocomputing.

You may get some users saying your question is opinion-based but I believe it will get an answer.

Comment: It [did indeed](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/27961/278) get an answer. It also became a Hot Network Question.

Answer (score 3):

[*Electrical Engineering*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), mentioned by Rubén, will not allow your question:

> consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when designing these products or modifying their electronics for other uses

Furthermore, "*you should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face*."

See also [this thread on their Meta](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7510/are-history-questions-on-topic-or-should-they-be-migrated-if-possible-to-hist).

---

[***History of Science and Mathematics***](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) seems a good fit.
They have well-received questions like

- [Why was Beaumont's steam engine not replicated for about 100 years?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/why-was-beaumonts-steam-engine-not-replicated-for-about-100-years)
- [What was worldwide supply of disk storage in 1969?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11217/what-was-worldwide-supply-of-disk-storage-in-1969)
- and even [Marx economics theory](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/14408/marx-economics-theory)

You can always ask on [their Meta](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/) to make sure.

On the other hand, [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/) might also accept your question. Even though yours is an open-ended question, the answer is possibly quite specific (the popularization of the Internet?). Besides, it's not nearly as broad as, e.g., [What caused the decline of the Spanish empire?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9234/what-caused-the-decline-of-the-spanish-empire) :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the bottom of https://stackexchange.com/sites. For your convenience, here is the text:

> Want to start your own Stack Exchange Q&A site? [Check out Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/). Our friendly robots are waiting

If you don't want to start your own Stack Exchange or you know that you aren't ready, as you should start after you have a community ready to participate in the proposal, you might try to find people willing to help on chatrooms of the related sites. Ref. [What are the benefits of chatrooms for asking questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329366/289691)

One of the related sites on the specifics about electronics might be [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). From their tour:

> Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiast

Some of the related questions

- [What exactly is happening when a graphing calculator LCD malfunctions when batteries are weak or overloaded?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/24672/271999)
- [Design plan for a calculator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/26942/271999)