# How should ask a question about involving a knowledge gap?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, subjective

How should I post a question asking for help to identify a knowledge gap?
Currently, I have an issue related to database design. In the legacy database that I am now in charge of maintaining, I've identified what I thought was a very nonoptimal table structure.

Bad column ordering, bad choice of data types, bad choice of indexing, ...

After I created a test to see the performance gains I would get I noticed little to no change in performance.

Now I know I've misunderstood something or I'm missing knowledge to explain the discrepancy between what I expected (performance gain) vs. what I actually got (no change).

After reading my post drafts I keep concluding that either the question is too broad or that the post would promote subjective answers.

Should I still ask questions of this nature and if so how would it need to be worded so that it isn't too broad?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking this on [database administrators meta](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: The example is very specific yes. But my post is for a general form of this idea (knowledge gap).

Comment: In general you'd ask on the site specific meta.

Comment: Firstly: what kind of "knowledge gap" are you asking about?

Comment: Would it be possible to show a link containing your database question draft?

Comment: [https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/151786/search-posts-by-userid-comment-text?CommentText=published&UserId=3404097#resultSets](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/151786/search-posts-by-userid-comment-text?CommentText=published&UserId=3404097#resultSets) PS Times askers said where they are in what process: once? (Textbook named a few times.) People literally do not know what they are doing. And know it. But won't act. PS [dba.se](https://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/151786/search-posts-by-userid-comment-text?CommentText=published&UserId=43932#resultSets)

Comment: In the particular case of your main question: You went ahead & wrote code, so where is the gap? You must have generated some 1st code change, that doesn't do what you expected, for some reason. What is stopping you from posting a SO/dba.SE MRE ([minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) (magic link [mre]) about that? PS My next 2 comments are my standard ones for (unresearched) SQL performance questions & (MRE-free) SQL code questions at SO/dba.SE.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) 
[mre] [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932) [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. \[ask] \[Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: "Should I still ask questions of this nature and if so how would it need to be worded so that it isn't too broad?" All questions are about some knowledge gap or another. Just keep it focused. In order keep it focused, ask for specific as possible details of the problem you are facing (simplify if needed before) and search before to close the knowledge gap sufficiently. StackOverflow specifically is not sufficient to master programming.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a [Problem X Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/289691). Instead of asking this here, you should start by learning the workings of one of the 183 Stack Exchange sites.

Considering the example provided, where the knowledge gap gravitates around *database*, you might reduce the list by focusing on one having  *database* in their name, like [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), or try a site like [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), or go to the flagship: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com). Why? Because *[database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database)* looks to be the key concept.

It's worth mentioning that there is [a site for Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/) that can help self-learners with a self-learning plan.

In another case, try to identify the **core concept** and think about which disciplines, fields, professions, etc. might be related.

First, please look at the list of sites at https://stackexchange.com/sites and choose a site to become a member.

Once you are on the site homepage, click the ? (help) > Tour or the Tour link at the site footer.

Explore the site's main page, tags, Help Center, and Meta if needed. If the site doesn't look to meet your needs, try another site.

**Why?**

While the Q&A model and most of the *system artifacts* are the same for all the 183 Stack Exchange sites (Ask Question form, tags, etc.), each site has its own **community**. Each community has its own "communi-lity" like [personality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personality), but instead of referring to a [person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person), it is to a site's [community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community). Each community has its workings, culture, its *system of beliefs and values*, and results. I.E. On Stack Overflow, some tags have tag wikis with very extended guidance, including resources for beginner, intermediate and advanced **learners** / **practitioners** about the topic referred by the tag. An example of this is [php](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info).

Not all the "knowledge gaps" issues are solved by "asking a question", understanding this as clicking on the **Ask Question** button, filling in the fields and finding a way to finally get *the system* to allow the question to be submitted on a Stack Exchange site. Still, some Stack Exchange communities have worked together to help people grow around specific topics. There are chances that the solution that you need might have a different path to be found.

One option might be to use the chat. See [What are the benefits of chatrooms for asking questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329366/289691).

There is no certainty that there will be one among the 183 Stack Exchange sites that will always satisfy your needs to solve your "knowledge gaps" issues. If you eventually find an off-Stack Exchange Network *learning community* to accompany you through your growth journey, remember that you can propose a new site on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com). Still, you should already have a community ready to work on the site proposal and the private beta. Otherwise, the site proposal will not be approved, or the private beta will not become a public beta.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you believe you have unknown unknowns, then most likely it will simply not be possible to ask the question. Sorry. Please keep in mind that Stack Exchange sites are not help desks, and as such they are **not about** helping you; they are about answering questions. It is not our concern whether you know how to ask that question, and if you don't, there is precious little we can do about that.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is about specific term which is "knowledge gap" I'll try to address it in general.

First, what is exactly a "knowledge gap"? It means you lack knowledge about something, but in a way you can't learn this by single Google question, or even single question on Stack Exchange site.

So it means, essentially, that you're correct in your assumption and such a question has a high chance of being closed, on any Stack Exchange site, even if its topic fits the site's scope.

What to do? Ideally, fill the gap yourself by learning about the subject, be it with blog posts, online courses, and even Stack Exchange posts about it. When you feel like you learned enough but still can't tackle the problem, then it's time to ask on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I used to think exactly this way. Stack Exchange has 182 sites. Even though many sites have mods that are mods on multiple sites and / or are users of other sites, I have gotten surprising feedback when participating in some sites using my association bonus. While I was "aware" that each site might have its own *consensus*, I didn't expect that there would be so big differences in how the "rules" would be interpreted across the network. Also, I have been surprised about how **a few** association bonus users behave on the site I moderate, and that behavior be considered "normal".

Comment: My point is *Your mileage might vary!*. Mine have varied, from site to site, from day to day. It never has been boring.

Comment: @Rubén not 100% sure what you mean, but yes, each site is different, and it can be great difference sometimes. Still, I don't think there's any site in SE that will accept question asking to fill a gap for the OP, if there is, might edit it into my answer.

Comment: Regarding "fill a gap", just to mention one site, Stack Overflow has users, IIRC, *profiled* as "always helpers" who answer any "question". This is  one of the related SO meta posts [Curation and cynicism: Or why Stack Overflow sometimes doesn't seem welcoming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367016/1595451): "Helpers can become Always Helpers. They believe that every question deserves an answer"